# TALEND UPDATE FILA

Tags: sql-server, condiciones

Buenas, estoy actualizando una base de datos desde un fichero .txt, en concreto estoy actualizando los valores siguientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el tmap hago la relación correspondiente entre los datos del .txt y los atributos de la base de datos y acto seguido hago el update en una base de datos sqlserver, donde pone "maquina".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que siempre estoy actualizando la BD, aunque los datos que reciba del .txt estén en blanco. Básicamente, la fila "transaccio" solo quiero actualizarla en la base de datos cuando tenga un campo de tipo "date" o simplemente contenga algún dato.

Estoy seguro que con el TMAP hay alguna manera de hacer que solo se ponga en la base de datos cuando exista algo pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, veo que tienes esta pregunta en ingles  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5864/talend-update-database-condition puedes borrarla ahora que creaste esta otra, la cual se adapta el idioma del sitio puede ver el boton eliminar al pie de la pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.
en `Tmap` tienes la opción de `Nullable`. Si desmarcas la opción no debería de obtener registros provenientes de un fichero con celda `NULL`, y obtener únicamente los datos relevantes.
Otra manera es meter un `tfilterow` y filtrar exclusivamente en las columnas que tenga cualquier tipo de dato, y así conseguirás que solo lo que tenga datos se integre en base de datos.
Espero que te sirva, un saludo.
También puedes crear una rutina:

```
 public static String yumeteo(String dato)
    {                 

     {
            try {

            if (dato.compareTo("")!=0){                 
                return "Vacio"
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "KO";
```

con esto consigues que en la celda vacía ponga "Vacio" y con un `textractregexfields` puedas obtener todas las filas que tienen este String y excluirlo de la carga.
Espero que te ayude